# java.lang.NullPointerException in onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) for Button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have created a button in onCreate() method of Activity, and try to change the state of button in 
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) method.
I have only one line in this method.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
savedButton.setSelected(true);
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

but some time java.lang.NullPointerException exception occur at this line where I have change the button state, and some time it works fine.

Where I am wrong?

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.MainActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(MainActivity.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:934)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can it be that it doens't know `savedButton` at some point?

Comment: Please give us some more code around this line.

Comment: @Bigflow But onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) method executed after onCreate() and savedButton is created correctly in this method.

Comment: Can you post the logcat please?

Comment: @LokiSinclair Added log cat.

Comment: Is this not a case of needing to put the super call before any other method call. Seeing as you're recreating the saved state, maybe the button is yet to be created and thus the null pointer. Obviously the super call can sometimes go anywhere, but I tend to place it before any other calls, in most instances unless I have specific need to do things before hand. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Put this

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    savedButton.setSelected(true);
}
```

into your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` instead, after you define the button.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried this solution and it was solved the problem, but I want to know why NullPointerException in onRestoreInstanceState() method.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. My guess is somewhere in your code you have modified the definition savedButton. If you have only assign the savedButton once in onCreate() and never change it, then we cannot really tell unless you post the full code.